# Routing in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'm new to laravel and im building my first api.
I have several routes that have the same prefix and i was wondering if its possible to group them under one route group and switch the last part of the uri to match the controller i need

Here is a example

main prefix: 'tenant'
possible routes: 'tenant/email_template' , 'tenant/review' , 'tenant/static_metas'

the routing that i want to achieve its something like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'tenant/{entity}' , 'middleware' => 'auth'], function($router){

       Route::post('{entity}/create', '{entity}Controller@create)->name({entity}.create);

});
```

Where the entity stand for the last part of the uri , if i give 'tenant/static_metas' i want to take the last part of the uri 'static_metas' and bind it to a create method calling the static_meta controller and its create method.
The reason behind this its to avoid rewriting  the CRUD routes n-times changing only the controller and the uri.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6kyfSmPhn8&ab_channel=LaravelDaily the best explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do that, just use for loop.
And also the preferred group syntax is to separate `prefix` and `middleware` part into its own function with group having only closure.

```
$entities = ['email_template', 'review', 'static_metas'];

foreach($entities as $entity) {
    Route::prefix("tenant/{$entity}")
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->group(function($router) use ($entity) {
            $studEntity = \Str::studly($entity);
            Route::post("{$entity}/create", "{$studEntity}Controller@create")
                ->name("{$entity}.create");
        });
}
```

Also you should use Resource controller for consistent CRUD operations. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers